# How to find the current in the diagram

Tags: current-source

I am struggling on how to find the current for Id in the below circuit diagram. Please assist.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the same current flowing through the \$? A\$ as through the \$5 A\$, but reverse?

Comment: The question itself is not consistent

Comment: Can you show us the work that you've done so far?  Also, please verify that you have drawn the circuit correctly, a few things seem inconsistent. Edit the circuit if needed.

Comment: You have shown no effort of your own. We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Honestly, the answer is not obvious to you? Assuming it is drawn correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Your example has some weird magic going on.

\$I_{d}=-I_{a}= -5A\$

Also

\$I_{d}+I_{o}+I_{c}+I{x}=0\$

\$I_{d}+7A+4A+1A=0\$

\$I_{d}=-12A\$

This example is incorrect and cannot be solved!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some magic going on Id = -Ia.

Comment: I think there is some magic going on in the schematic, Just look at Ib and Ic.

Comment: And Io = 7A derived from Ia=5A with no other source.

Comment: Doesn't look like a proper circuit.

Comment: More than magic, either the circuit is drawn wrong or there is an extra current source missing. Or it might be the old FM principle.